# Optimization - Two similar method

Tags: php, design-patterns, copy-paste, symfony

I'm new in Symfony and i have a little problem.
I been searching online, couldn't find the answer to my problem.
I create API and I have two controllers(UserController, InstructorController) with similar method (addUserImage, addInstructorImage). I created abstract BaseImage(Here is saving files), InstructorImage and UserImage(here are set path). This is my controller:

```
/**
 * @ApiDoc(
 *  name="addInstructorImage", section="Instructors",
 *  description="Add Instructor Image",
 * )
 *
 * @Route("/instructor/{instructor}/image", name="instructors.image.add")
 * @Method("POST")
 *
 * @param Request    $request
 * @param Instructor $instructor
 * @View
 *
 * @return \FOS\RestBundle\View\View
 */
public function addInstructorImage(Request $request, Instructor $instructor)
{
    $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('edit', $instructor->getUser());
    $image = new InstructorImage();
    $form = $this->get('form.factory')
            ->createNamed('', InstructorImageType::class, $image, ['csrf_protection' => false, 'method' => 'POST']);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $image->setInstructor($instructor);
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($image);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->view(null, Response::HTTP_NO_CONTENT);
    }

    return $this->view($form, Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

My second controller is identical. 
The only difference is another object , and another form. What is the best way to optimize this code. Should I create services that adds photos or use chain handler? Maybe You have better ideas?
Thank you for your help

Comment: I guess this question fits much better to [ProgrammersStack](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) - just in case you don not get a good answer here.

Comment: @Jurik when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: Of course Wojciech should delete this unanswered question immediately. @gnat - it would be helpful if you could flag it for migration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: Don't waste time on trying to optimize this sort of stuff.

Your method consist of 19 lines of code.  It's all basic boiler plate easy to read code.  I know whenever I see duplicate code I'm tempted to try and combine it somehow but what exactly would be gaining?  Reducing 19 lines to maybe 15?

If I was going to change your code then I'd be tempted to move some of the business logic into it's own service.  Something like:

```
InstructorManager::addImage($instructor,$image);
```

That would get rid of the entity manager boiler plate and provide a bit of abstraction.  Might make it a bit easier to test though all the method is doing is setting the image and calling flush.  Hardly worth the effort.  Might be worth it if you have other manager type functionality to add as well.  Or maybe you want to be able to add images from a console app.

Of course you may end needing to add functionality in the future.  Maybe you want to notify someone when the image is changed.  If you find yourself needing to modify duplicated code then you can probably justify the effort of moving common code into it's own service.

And I suppose you could create a service for your form using the container's factory capability.  Especially if you had a bunch of these form to make.  But again, hardly worth the effort and might even make things more difficult to maintain.